# Xperia V require root permissions every time

Tags: rooting

I have Xperia V 9.1.A.1.140 and I just rooted it using "Root Many Android" (see [closer decription on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460&highlight=xperia%20v)), and now I installed Titanium Backup and every time the app loads it requires permissions multiple times and every time I try to uninstall and app, why is that?

EDIT: And here is the solution - I also rooted it with *motochopper* (again [described at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2228613)) which installs the SuperSU, and in now only asks the SuperSU for permissions only once and it's working fine now.

Comment: Boris, could you please give us some more details: 1) What is "this method"? (a few words on the tool used would be helpful; for full information one still can follow the link); 2) What kind of super-user app are you using (SuperSU, SuperUser by ChainDD, SuperUser by ClockworkMod/Koushik)? 3) On the popup, is there a box to make the grant permanent (usually labeled "remember") or something similar, and did you try that? 4) What do you mean by "try to uninstall and app" (maybe you meant "everytime I try to uninstall an app"?)?

Comment: actually I did it with another method from XDA http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2228613
with this it installs the SuperSU and then it only asks it for permissions only once, and it works fine now

Comment: Which means your problem is solved? In that case you might think about a) updating your question to make it easier understandable (as described in my previous comment) plus adding your solution with a few more details as well, or b) removing your question if a) is too much work :)

Comment: check it now, better?

Comment: Well: An answer is an *answer*, not part of the question :) You should post it *below*, where it says "Your answer", and then can accept it after the technical two-days delay, so it shows up as "solved issue" in searches. It would also help to *name* the methods instead of only calling them "this" and "this other", so people would not have to look behind links for basic information (see my edit ;).

Comment: ok, will answer it tommorow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did:
First I tried Bin4ry method's from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460&highlight=xperia%20v)
with the 3rd option, it installs Superuser, but its buggy and it doesn't remember the permissions.

So then I did it with Motochopper method from [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2228613) 
which installs SuperSU, and the root apps now require permissions from SuperSU just once, and it's working fine.

After that I safely deleted Superuser.